# Add y-axis labels to each facet_grid plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot that you can simply reproduce with

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

tibble(x = sample.int(3, 1000, replace = T),
       y = sample(letters[1:3], 1000, replace = T),
       k = sample(LETTERS[4:6], 1000, replace = T)) %>%
  count(x,y,k) %>%
  ggplot(aes(k, n)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(x ~ y)
```

which gives something like the plot below (depends on random sampling):

[image]

I want to add y labels to each axis, but still be able to use facet_grid layout. Mostly beacause I need labels for each row of plots and not above them. In this case it might sound weird but in my data I have a 5x6 grid of plots and there are 10 labels on y axis. This would simplify readability of the whole plot.

I want to achieve plot like this:

[image]

Comment: `facet_grid(x ~ y, scales="free_y")`?

Comment: @user2974951 this achieves nothing. **free_y** value of **scales** only frees the per-row labels if they were different (so here it changes nothing). Still doesn't add y axis labels to each plot. This would be the case for facet_wrap but not here.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it using `facet_wrap`, but it changes the layout.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

tibble(x = sample.int(3, 1000, replace = T),
       y = sample(letters[1:3], 1000, replace = T),
       k = sample(LETTERS[4:6], 1000, replace = T)) %>%
  count(x,y,k) %>%
  ggplot(aes(k, n)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~ interaction(x, y), scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: I know I can achieve this with facet_wrap but as I mentioned in post, I do need to have the label for row. 1) Need to fit 6 plots there so it's better to have it rowwise 2) The data context makes it so rowwise visualisation is easier to read.

Comment: If you need the label for row, you can use strip.position : `facet_wrap(~ interaction(x, y), scales = "free_y", strip.position = "right")`. But I don't know any way to get both the row and column label